# script to restore database sql server from bak file, doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, database-restore, sql-scripts

I have an empty database:

`DB_Clients`

And I want to restore the database from a `.bak` file:

```
OldDBClients.bak
```

This is the path:

```
C:\OldDBClients.bak
```

And this is my script:

```
USE [master]
GO
    RESTORE DATABASE DB_Clients
    FROM DISK = 'C:\OldDBClients.bak'
```

When I execute it, I get this error message:

> Msg 3154, Level 16, State 4, Line 15
>   The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'DB_Clients' database.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Can someone tell me why this happen?
I have to point that the file has the permissions to read and write.

Thank's.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to use `WITH REPLACE` option in order to overwrite the existing database.

```
RESTORE DATABASE DB_Clients
FROM DISK = 'C:\OldDBClients.bak'
WITH REPLACE
```

Probably you also need to specify `WITH MOVE` options; in this case:

- use `RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\OldDBClients.bak'` to know logical name of your MDF/LDF
- use `WITH MOVE` options in your RESTORE

For example:

```
RESTORE DATABASE DB_Clients
FROM DISK = 'C:\OldDBClients.bak'
WITH REPLACE,
MOVE 'YourMDFLogicalName' TO '<MDF file path>',
MOVE 'YourLDFLogicalName' TO '<LDF file path>'
```

Please note that you can also `DROP` your empty `DB_Clients` database and use a simple `RESTORE`.

Comment: I get this error:                                                                                                 ' Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file. '

Comment: Thank's for your help ; -D

Comment: FYI - Above syntax is incorrect - Would need to remove the 2nd `WITH` after the comma for this to be valid syntax

Answer (score 14):

You should this syntax:

```
USE [master]
GO
RESTORE DATABASE DB_Clients FROM DISK = 'C:\OldDBClients.bak' WITH 
MOVE 'DB_Clients' TO 'D:\SQLServer\Data\DB_Clients.mdf',
MOVE 'DB_Clients_log' TO 'D:\SQLServer\Log\DB_Clients.ldf', REPLACE
```

It instructs SQL Server to overwrite the existing copy and specifies a valid location for your data and log files

Comment: *Your code give me this error:  *                                                                                                                                              Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: I get this error: ' Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file. '

Comment: I added `WITH MOVE`. You will have to replace the paths with a valid location on your system.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ;-D

Answer (score 7):

Step 1:
Check the logical file names with the help of the following command:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
FROM DISK = 'E:\DBBackups\mydb.bak'
```

Step 2: Use the logical names you get from the above query in the below query:

```
 RESTORE DATABASE [mydb_new]
  FILE = N'<MDFLogicalName>'
  FROM DISK = N'E:\DBBackups\mydb.bak'
  WITH 
    FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10,
    MOVE N'<MDFLogicalname>'
    TO N'E:\DBBackups\mydb_new.mdf',
    MOVE N'<LDFLogicalName>'
    TO N'E:\DBBackups\mydb_new_0.ldf'
```

After running the above commands with the correct values you will see the output like this:

```
10 percent processed.
20 percent processed.
30 percent processed.
40 percent processed.
50 percent processed.
60 percent processed.
70 percent processed.
80 percent processed.
90 percent processed.
100 percent processed.
Processed 7672 pages for database 'mydb_new', file '<MDFLogicalname>' on file 1.
Processed 5 pages for database 'mydb_new', file '<LDFLogicalName>' on file 1.
RESTORE DATABASE ... FILE=<name> successfully processed 7677 pages in 0.780 seconds (76.893 MB/sec).

Completion time: 2019-10-20T11:35:31.8343787+05:30
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of file = 1 ?